# Regex required for space delimited strings java

Tags: java, regex, boost-regex, regex-greedy, regex-lookarounds

I have an operation that deals with many space delimited strings, I am looking for a regex for the String matches function which will trigger pass if first two strings before first space starts with capital letters and will return false if they are not.

Examples:

```
"AL_RIT_121 PA_YT_32 rit cell 22 pulse"
```

will return true as first two substring `AL_RIT_121` and `PA_YT_32` starts with capital letter `A` and `P` respectively

```
"AL_RIT_252 pa_YT_21 mal cell reg 32 1 ri"
```

will return false as `p` is in lower case.

Comment: your question doesn't make sence.  your first space between `AL_RIT_121` and `PA_YT_32`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply `string.matches("[A-Z]\\w+ [A-Z].*")`

Comment: Thanks for the pattern it suffies my criteria :)

Answer (score 6):

```
Pattern.compile("^\\p{Lu}\\S*\\s+\\p{Lu}")
```

will work with the `.find()` method.  There's no reason to use `matches` on a prefix test, but if you have an external constraint, just do

```
Pattern.compile("^\\p{Lu}\\S*\\s+\\p{Lu}.*", Pattern.DOTALL)
```

To break this down:

1. `^` matches the start of the string,
2. `\\p{Lu}` matches any upper-case letter,
3. `\\S*` matches zero or more non-space characters, including `_`
4. `\\s+` matches one or more space characters, and
5. the second `\\p{Lu}` matches the upper-case letter starting the second word.

In the second variant, `.*` combined with `Pattern.DOTALL` matches the rest of the input.

Comment: You don't really have to put `\p{Lu}` in square brackets; like `\s` and `\S`, it can stand alone.  And it's `DOTALL`, not `DOT_ALL`.  I almost always have to look that up, in Python as well as in Java, but they both spell it without the underscore.

Comment: Thanks a lot to you all, the provided regex worked perfectly for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a specific regex if those two examples demonstrate your input format:

```
^(?:[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+_\d+\s*)+
```

Which means:

```
^           - Match the beginning of the string
(?:         - Start a non-capturing group (used to repeat the following)
    [A-Z]+  - Match one or more uppercase characters
    _       - Match an underscore
    [A-Z]+  - Match one or more uppercase characters
    _       - Match an underscore
    \d+     - Match one or more decimals (0-9)
    \s*     - Match zero or more space characters
)+          - Repeat the above group one or more times
```

You would use it in Java like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?:[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+_\\d+\\s*)+");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher( inputString);
if( matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println( "Match found.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String text = "AL_RIT_121 pA_YT_32 rit cell 22 pulse";

    boolean areFirstTwoWordsCapitalized = areFirstTwoWordsCapitalized(text);

    System.out.println("areFirstTwoWordsCapitalized = <" + areFirstTwoWordsCapitalized + ">");

}

private static boolean areFirstTwoWordsCapitalized(String text)
{
    boolean rslt = false;

    String[] words = text.split("\\s");

    int wordIndx = 0;

    boolean frstWordCap = false;
    boolean scndWordCap = false;

    for(String word : words)
    {
        wordIndx++;

        //System.out.println("word = <" + word + ">");

        Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z].+");

        Matcher mtchr = ptrn.matcher(word);

        while(mtchr.find())
        {
            String match = mtchr.group();

            //System.out.println("\tMatch = <" + match + ">");

            if(wordIndx == 1)
            {
                frstWordCap = true;
            }
            else if(wordIndx == 2)
            {
                scndWordCap = true;
            }
        }
    }

    rslt = frstWordCap && scndWordCap;

    return rslt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class RegularExp 
{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "[A-Z][^\\s.]*\\s[A-Z].*";
        String str = "APzsnnm lmn Dlld";
        System.out.println(str.matches(regex));

    }

}
```